# How to handle STI and build related models automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I'm building CMS and I want to assign to Page many different contents with common position in a grid and embedded models like plugins and html snippets. As I see for these requirements fit well STI approach.
How to build automatically inherited `Content` models when I provide params like in (if I'm not wrong) `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with content_type and specific model params?

Current STI logic:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  # string :name
  # string :link
  has_many :contents
  has_many :plugin_contents
  has_many :html_contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  # string :content_type
  # string :name
  # integer :position
  # integer :page_id
  belongs_to :page
  self.inheritance_column = :content_type

  def content_type
    case content_type
    when 'plugin'
      Plugin.new
    when 'snippet'
      Html.new
    end
  end
end

class Plugin < Content
  # string :url_params
  # string :own_name
end

class Html < Content
  # string :snippet
end
```

How to build it? My current approach e.g.:

```
page = Page.new(name: "Main Page with Plugins", link: "mianpage")
content_plugin1 = page.contents.build
content_plugin1.content_type = "plugin"
content_plugin1.position = 0
# Next how to pass Plugin params?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define the associations like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
  has_many :plugins
  has_many :htmls
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
end

class Plugin < Content
end

class Html < Content
end
```

Then you can create e.q. a associated `plugin` like this:

```
page = Page.create(name: "Main Page with Plugins", link: "mianpage")
plugin = page.plugins.build(
  name: 'foo', url_params: 'bar', own_name: 'baz', position: 0
)
plugin.save
```

The rule of thumb is: Whenever you start to set the STI's `type` yourself, then you do something wrong.